# Can I extract binary data that I can inspect while debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, pdf, visual-studio-2013

I'm debugging an application which is producing PDFs, which get sent to a location I don't have access to. I want an example of one of the PDF files. When I'm debugging, I am able to inspect the appropriate object at one point where the data for the PDF is stored as a byte array.

It seems like it should be possible to extract that binary data, save it to a file, call it a .pdf and view it. Is this possible? I could pull the application apart in several different ways to get it to output the PDF to the browser, but that's pretty messy as the logic for this is buried fairly deep down.

Comment: How is your application *producing PDFs*? It very much depends on **A** the PDF library in question and **B** the way you use it. E.g. iTextSharp usually does not keep a complete image of the resulting PDF in memory but instead streams parts to the output as soon as these parts are finished (so it **does not** hold the data you ask for in memory); but in some applications this output stream is a memory stream (which then **does** hold the data you ask for in memory).

Comment: It'd take a while to determine exactly how it's doing it, but the key point is that the pdf data is available as a bytearray during debugging

Comment: If it is available, what keeps you from trying?

Comment: Prior to seeing Philip Pittle's answer, a method to try, hence the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add a utility method somewhere in your code base that writes the byte array to disk using the [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.  For example:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void WriteBytesToTempFile(byte[] fileContent)
{
    var tempFileName = "c:\temp.pdf";

    if (File.Exists(tempFileName))
        File.Delete(tempFileName);

    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(tempFileName, FileMode.Create)))
    {
       writer.Write(fileContent);
    }
 }
```

When you are debugger you can then use the [Visual Studio Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) to call the method and pass in your pdf bytes.

Or you can call the method directly from your code.  I've added the [Conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) Attribute so the method will only be called if you compile using "debug".  The compiler will omit the method call if you compile using the "release" profile.

Comment: That looks a pretty neat solution, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Also, depending on your execution environment, you might not have write access to `c:\ `.  In that case you can use `Path.GetTempPath()` to write to the temp directory.  See here for more:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/path-gettemppath